Python Pulp Query - allocate task within timerange to achieve objective to minimize number of resource
Objective
Minimize the number of resource to handle all requirements
The input that we have is list of requirements which needs to be allocated to any one of the resource from list of resource that can be mapped.
Each requirement needs to be allocated for duration as per no of hours requested and within the range of dates provided in request.
Start date and end date range format w 24w211 is 2024 week 21 and day 1(Monday)
Challenge
The code that I shared below allocates resource from start date(Available range(start day)) in input, it doesn’t find out from given range of days(Available range(start day)     Available range(end day)), which date is best to have as start date so that the total number of cars to be manufactured can be minimized.
For eg: In below sample input – req 1 can be allocated to any resource and for any 3 weeks from range provided. The number of weeks in request 1 is 3 weeks(120/40) which can be allocated from
22W211 to 22W235 or 22W221 to 22W245 or 22W231 to 22W255 or 22W241 to 22W265 etc
Sample input



Req ID
Nr.hrs to allocate
Available range(start day)
Available range(end day)
List of resource to which the requirement can be mapped




1
120
22W211
22W305
RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4


2
40
22W211
22W225
RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4


3
80
22W211
22W305
RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4


4
8
21W231
21W255
RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4


5
24
21W231
21W255
RES2, RES3, RES4


6
16
21W231
21W255
RES2, RES3, RES4


7
120
22W251
22W275
RES2, RES3, RES4


8
240
22W211
22W305
RES2, RES3, RES4


9
40
22W211
22W225
RES2, RES3, RES4


10
120
22W211
22W255
RES2



def solve_group(res_pool, reqs):
# Initialize the linear programming problem
prob = LpProblem(f"Minimize_ress_Group_{res_pool}", LpMinimize)
# Step 2.1: Define variables
# Decision variable x_ijk = 1 if res i is assigned to request j starting at week k
x = {}
for res in res_pool:
    for req in reqs:
        for start_day in range(req['start_day'], req['end_day'] + 2 - req['hours_required'] // 8 - (1 if req['hours_required'] % 8 > 0 else 0)  ):
            x[res, req['req_id'], start_day] = LpVariable(f"x_{res}_{req['req_id']}_{start_day}", 0, 1, LpBinary)

# Step 2.2: Define binary variable for res usage
# Binary variable used_i = 1 if res i is used
used = {}
for res in res_pool:
    used[res] = LpVariable(f"used_{res}", 0, 1, LpBinary)

# Step 3: Objective function - Minimize the number of ress used
prob += lpSum(used[res] for res in res_pool), "Minimize number of res"

# Step 4: Constraints
# Step 4.1: Every request must be fulfilled
for req in reqs:
    prob += lpSum(x[res, req['req_id'], start_day] 
                    for res in req['pnos'] 
                    for start_day in range(req['start_day'], req['end_day'] + 2 - req['hours_required'] // 8 - (1 if req['hours_required'] % 8 > 0 else 0))) == 1, f"Fulfill_req_{req['req_id']}"
                
# Step 4.2: Non-overlapping constraint - No res can be double-booked for overlapping periods
for res in res_pool:
    for day in range(min(req['start_day'] for req in reqs), max(req['end_day'] for req in reqs)):
        prob += lpSum(x[res, req['req_id'], start_day] 
                      for req in reqs 
                      for start_day in range(req['start_day'], req['end_day'] + 2 - req['hours_required'] // 8 - (1 if req['hours_required'] % 8 > 0 else 0) ) 
                      if start_day <= day < start_day + (req['hours_required'] // 8 + (1 if req['hours_required'] % 8 > 0 else 0) )) <= 1, f"No_double_booking_{res}_{day}"

# Step 4.3: Link res usage with assignment
for res in res_pool:
    for req in reqs:
        for start_day in range(req['start_day'], req['end_day'] + 2 - req['hours_required'] // 8 - (1 if req['hours_required'] % 8 > 0 else 0) ):
            prob += used[res] >= x[res, req['req_id'], start_day], f"Link_usage_{res}_{req['req_id']}_{start_day}"

# Step 5: Solve the problem for this group
prob.solve()

# Return the result (the number of res used and their assignments)
return prob, used, x

Another example:
Also if Consider the are 3 requirements, req 1 has need for 1 week with range of 24w20 and 24w22 and req 2, req 3 also has same requirement. In this case all three can be assigned to one resource, req1 can be mapped on 24w20 and req2 can be mapped to 24w21 and req2 can be mapped to 24w22. This way we minimised number of resource needed for handling all requirements

"Any 3 weeks from the range provided", at a granularity of one day? As in, the period does not necessarily need to start at the beginning of a week?

No of hours required is the need i.e the time that needs to be allocated for requirement for selected resource. But also each requirement there is time window which is start week and end week. So we need to allocate best possible time within that range which can help to reduce the total number of resource to mange list of requirement.

Yes we need to assign at a granularity of 1 day. The star date and end date can be any day between the range. No of hours to allocate can be divided by 8 and used as days for the model

In your example, req 1 needs 3 weeks, and you say it can be done "22W211 to 22W235".  That's 24 weeks.  Why isn't it just any group of 3 weeks?  Presumably continuous group...

Surely that means 24 days and not 24 weeks.

Hi AirSquid, in that available 10 weeks for req1 any continuous 3 weeks can be assigned for this requirement. That range needs to be leveraged to reduce number of resource needed. There will be some requirements which provides less range and some more range.

OK.  @Reinderien.  Yes, I thought it might be days too, but it's 24 days and 3 weeks is 21 days in my book, so I don't understand the time blocking unless that's a typo replicated in all the example segments.

Further, if you look at the possible start times for items 3&4 you have (presumably) some calendar reference for 21W231 and 22W211.  So, how do these timeslots relate?  What is the significance of 21W and 22W?  Is that part a throw away and are we working just on days [1, 365]-- which seems appropriate for a by-day model.

Hi AirSquid, Start date and end date range format w 24w211 is 2024 week 21 and day 1(Monday). There is function where we are converting this date to a number for scheduling purpose

This is a volunteer service. I actually am (slowly) working on an example, but there is no impact to urgency here; or, said another way, urgency should translate into you making this an actual runnable MCVE which it still isn't.

Hi Reinderien, thank you! I am not able to share complete code due to restrictions. My apologies

Let's be serious.  You can't share because none of that is working.  It's riddled with illegal statements and is not structured properly at all.  There isn't really much community value to this question as it is more of a request to code it up for you from scratch rather than a technical question on a particular aspect of the effort.  Perhaps someone with some spare time will code it up.

Hi AirSquid, I value all of your time. I do not want anyone to code anything from stratch. could you please guide only on below point:

We have created 3 binary variables - one is list of resource, second is copy of resource and third is assignment variable which have 2*2 matrix for req to resource mapping
current code works well to reduce the number of resource that is needed to map all requirements
current constraint that is added is considering requirement start week and end week requested to map the requirement, it is not leveraging the range and find best possible days to map


if anyone can just guide me how to create a constraint in which i can say Assignment of req to resource should be between the range and equal to requested days, i can resolve the issue. this is first time i am working with linear programming, hence struggling

the code that i shared works very well, but its not considering the range to assign, its taking start week day as start day by default, the below constraint
for day in range(min([need['start_day'] for need in Requirements]),
max([need['end_day'] for need in Requirements]) + 1):
for j, RES in enumerate(RES_List+ list(RES_LIST_copied)):
prob += pulp.lpSum([ASSIGNMENT[i][j] for i, need in enumerate(Requirements) if
day >= need['start_day'] and day <= need['end_day']]) <= 1

The following answer describes the theoretical optimisation approach, data processing steps, and output; but does not include verbatim code because I'm not compelled to spoon-feed the OP.
Use Pandas. It's the only practical way to manage this dataset, especially due to the non-trivial date manipulation necessary. Replace your long column names with short (but still descriptive) ones.
The date format 22W211 is cursed - it's not useful in any processing context. As soon as you can, throw this away and replace it with a version parsed by format %yW%U%w. This can be done in one step in Pandas via pd.to_datetime.
Hour counts are also not helpful here. Convert to day counts by dividing by 8. Treat those counts as continuous and monotonic on a datetime index from Pandas date_range() using frequency B. Pay careful attention to the fact that the work-day dimension in integers referenced from some arbitrary epoch is not the same as calendar days, and if you attempt to perform math on the dates as calendar days it won't be valid.
Your resources being a series of comma-delimited strings is also useless in any processing context. Use Pandas str.split() followed by explode to convert to a long-form frame to represent requirement-resource combinations.
Create the following variables in PuLP:

any_used per resource: binary, whether that resource was used at all
asn_req_res per requirement and resource: binary, whether that requirement-resource pair was assigned
res_ok for every resource, first requirement and second requirement: binary, whether the first and second requirements are clear from schedule conflict. Skip rows for which the first and second requirement are the same.
start per requirement: continuous, the start of the contiguous schedule block for that requirement. This is in units of work days as referenced from some arbitrary epoch, and is bounded based on the Available range columns from the dataset.

Create the following constraints:

Per requirement, lpSum(asn_req_res) == 1: requirements must have exactly one resource assigned
Per res_ok: let M = 2*(latest work day - earliest work day); let slack = 2 - first res_ok - second res_ok; then constrain

(first res_ok - slack - 1)*M <= dist_x, where dist_x is the signed difference between the second start and the first end
(second res_ok - slack - 1)*M <= dist_y where dist_y is the signed difference between the first start and the second end
first res_ok + second res_ok == 1: either the first order must have no conflict, or the second order must have no conflict; i.e. for this resource and requirement pair, the requirement schedule segments must not conflict if both of the requirements are assigned to this resource


Per resource, M*any_used >= n_uses, where M is the number of resources and n_uses is the sum of asn_req_res for this resource

The objective is to minimize the sum of any_used. For your current input data, this executes in 0.03 seconds and produces the following output:
res_scheduling:
MINIMIZE
1*any_used_RES1 + 1*any_used_RES2 + 1*any_used_RES3 + 1*any_used_RES4 + 0
SUBJECT TO
req_unique_1: asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1') + asn_req_res_(1,_'RES2')
 + asn_req_res_(1,_'RES3') + asn_req_res_(1,_'RES4') = 1

req_unique_2: asn_req_res_(2,_'RES1') + asn_req_res_(2,_'RES2')
 + asn_req_res_(2,_'RES3') + asn_req_res_(2,_'RES4') = 1

req_unique_3: asn_req_res_(3,_'RES1') + asn_req_res_(3,_'RES2')
 + asn_req_res_(3,_'RES3') + asn_req_res_(3,_'RES4') = 1
...


res_ok_x_RES1_req1_2: 600 asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1')
 + 600 asn_req_res_(2,_'RES1') + 600 res_ok_('RES1',_1,_2) + start_1 - start_2
 <= 1785

res_ok_y_RES1_req1_2: 600 asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1')
 + 600 asn_req_res_(2,_'RES1') + 600 res_ok_('RES1',_2,_1) - start_1 + start_2
 <= 1795

either_ok_RES1_req1_2: res_ok_('RES1',_1,_2) + res_ok_('RES1',_2,_1) = 1

res_ok_x_RES1_req1_3: 600 asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1')
 + 600 asn_req_res_(3,_'RES1') + 600 res_ok_('RES1',_1,_3) + start_1 - start_3
 <= 1785

res_ok_y_RES1_req1_3: 600 asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1')
 + 600 asn_req_res_(3,_'RES1') + 600 res_ok_('RES1',_3,_1) - start_1 + start_3
 <= 1790

either_ok_RES1_req1_3: res_ok_('RES1',_1,_3) + res_ok_('RES1',_3,_1) = 1
...


any_used_RES1: 4 any_used_RES1 - asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1')
 - asn_req_res_(2,_'RES1') - asn_req_res_(3,_'RES1') - asn_req_res_(4,_'RES1')
 >= 0

any_used_RES2: 4 any_used_RES2 - asn_req_res_(1,_'RES2')
 - asn_req_res_(10,_'RES2') - asn_req_res_(2,_'RES2')
 - asn_req_res_(3,_'RES2') - asn_req_res_(4,_'RES2') - asn_req_res_(5,_'RES2')
 - asn_req_res_(6,_'RES2') - asn_req_res_(7,_'RES2') - asn_req_res_(8,_'RES2')
 - asn_req_res_(9,_'RES2') >= 0

any_used_RES3: 4 any_used_RES3 - asn_req_res_(1,_'RES3')
 - asn_req_res_(2,_'RES3') - asn_req_res_(3,_'RES3') - asn_req_res_(4,_'RES3')
 - asn_req_res_(5,_'RES3') - asn_req_res_(6,_'RES3') - asn_req_res_(7,_'RES3')
 - asn_req_res_(8,_'RES3') - asn_req_res_(9,_'RES3') >= 0

any_used_RES4: 4 any_used_RES4 - asn_req_res_(1,_'RES4')
 - asn_req_res_(2,_'RES4') - asn_req_res_(3,_'RES4') - asn_req_res_(4,_'RES4')
 - asn_req_res_(5,_'RES4') - asn_req_res_(6,_'RES4') - asn_req_res_(7,_'RES4')
 - asn_req_res_(8,_'RES4') - asn_req_res_(9,_'RES4') >= 0
...

VARIABLES
0 <= any_used_RES1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= any_used_RES2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= any_used_RES3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= any_used_RES4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_req_res_(1,_'RES1') <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_req_res_(1,_'RES2') <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_req_res_(1,_'RES3') <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_req_res_(1,_'RES4') <= 1 Integer
...

0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_1,_2) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_1,_3) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_1,_4) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_2,_1) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_2,_3) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_2,_4) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_3,_1) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_3,_2) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_3,_4) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_4,_1) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_4,_2) <= 1 Integer
0 <= res_ok_('RES1',_4,_3) <= 1 Integer
...

250 <= start_1 <= 285 Continuous
250 <= start_10 <= 260 Continuous
250 <= start_2 <= 255 Continuous
250 <= start_3 <= 290 Continuous
start_4 <= 14 Continuous
start_5 <= 12 Continuous
start_6 <= 13 Continuous
start_7 = 270 Continuous
250 <= start_8 <= 270 Continuous
250 <= start_9 <= 255 Continuous
...


Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 388 COLUMNS
At line 2501 RHS
At line 2885 BOUNDS
At line 3184 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 383 rows, 292 columns and 1544 elements
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                3.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               73
Time (CPU seconds):             0.03
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.03

The solution looks like
             hours  work_days start_code end_code   earliest latest_excl      start   end_excl                 resources  earliest_work_day  latest_work_day_excl resource
requirement                                                                                                                                                               
1              120       15.0     22W211   22W305 2022-05-23  2022-07-30 2022-07-11 2022-08-01  [RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4]                250                   300     RES2
2               40        5.0     22W211   22W225 2022-05-23  2022-06-04 2022-05-23 2022-05-30  [RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4]                250                   260     RES2
3               80       10.0     22W211   22W305 2022-05-23  2022-07-30 2022-07-18 2022-08-01  [RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4]                250                   300     RES4
4                8        1.0     21W231   21W255 2021-06-07  2021-06-26 2021-06-07 2021-06-08  [RES1, RES2, RES3, RES4]                  0                    15     RES3
5               24        3.0     21W231   21W255 2021-06-07  2021-06-26 2021-06-23 2021-06-28        [RES2, RES3, RES4]                  0                    15     RES4
6               16        2.0     21W231   21W255 2021-06-07  2021-06-26 2021-06-07 2021-06-09        [RES2, RES3, RES4]                  0                    15     RES4
7              120       15.0     22W251   22W275 2022-06-20  2022-07-09 2022-06-20 2022-07-11        [RES2, RES3, RES4]                270                   285     RES3
8              240       30.0     22W211   22W305 2022-05-23  2022-07-30 2022-05-23 2022-07-04        [RES2, RES3, RES4]                250                   300     RES4
9               40        5.0     22W211   22W225 2022-05-23  2022-06-04 2022-05-23 2022-05-30        [RES2, RES3, RES4]                250                   260     RES3
10             120       15.0     22W211   22W255 2022-05-23  2022-06-25 2022-05-30 2022-06-20                    [RES2]                250                   275     RES2

            resource      start   end_excl  work_days
requirement                                          
2               RES2 2022-05-23 2022-05-30        5.0
10              RES2 2022-05-30 2022-06-20       15.0
1               RES2 2022-07-11 2022-08-01       15.0
4               RES3 2021-06-07 2021-06-08        1.0
9               RES3 2022-05-23 2022-05-30        5.0
7               RES3 2022-06-20 2022-07-11       15.0
6               RES4 2021-06-07 2021-06-09        2.0
5               RES4 2021-06-23 2021-06-28        3.0
8               RES4 2022-05-23 2022-07-04       30.0
3               RES4 2022-07-18 2022-08-01       10.0

